# Add to backstack

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I’m using [Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) as my navigation stack.

I would like to build following back stack as I want my users to land back on screen B on back press on Screen C.

```
A -> B -> C
```

Currently I’m doing

```kotlin
fun navigateToScreenC() {
   findNavController().navigate(R.id.nav_B)
   findNavController().navigate(R.id.nav_C)
}
```

This causes a visual flicker/glitch where screen B is temporarily visible.
Functionally however it does work!

Another option is to navigate to screen C and override the back button.
While this might work, I don’t wish to couple screen C’s back navigation to a forward navigation to Screen B.

I also saw the `backQueue` on the `NavController` is public and can be mutated in code.
However I was not successful in injecting a custom `NavBackStackEntry` and could not find any reference in the documentation on how to do so.

```kotlin
/**
 * Retrieve the current back stack.
 *
 * @return The current back stack.
 * @hide
 */
@get:RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP)
public open val backQueue: ArrayDeque<NavBackStackEntry> = ArrayDeque()
```

What is the correct way to programmatically add items to the backstack with Jetpack’s Navigation Library?

Comment: navigateToScreenC this function why you are using navigate(R.id.nav_B)?

Comment: I want to be able to navigate to Screen C, but a back press on Screen C should NOT open Screen A. It should open Screen B.
How can I do this?